# C - get all substrings between two delimiters

Tags: c, char, substring, strtok, strstr

I am trying to create an application that responds to multiple commands inputted by the users. The problem is that these commands have multiple parameters. Some examples would be

```
login 'username' 'password'
add song 'song_name' 'description' 'genre' 'link'
```

The input is read into a char array.

```
char recv[max]=" ";
if (read (fd, recv, sizeof (recv)) < 0)
    {
        perror ("[server]Error on read () from client.\n");
        return errno;
    }
```

This is all part of a bigger uni project using servers, so that is the reason for using read(). max is defined as 1024.

While I can use strstr() to identify which command is which, I'm not sure how I could get the username, password and so on as separate substrings.

I know that I can get rid of the command part by copying into another char the input+the command length, as it is fixed, but I'm keen on finding out how I can select each substring between two ''s. Would strtok() do the job?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strtok` can split on spaces, for example. It will not handle quoted strings though (e.g. it will split on a space even if it's inside the quoted `'description'`). The only 'standard' tool that can handle this is, probably, `lex`. But it might be simpler to write your own tokenizer reading the string char-by-char.

Comment: Would formatting the input in a different manner make it any easier? For example, using different delimiters (or none at all)

Comment: Yes. For example you can have a number telling you the length of the following string, thus avoiding any problems with quoting and escaping. You can also use binary encoded packets, thus side-stepping any string parsing altogether.

Comment: You should capture the return value from `read` and teminate any "string" data.

Comment: I was thinking now of finding the first and second ', copying the substring somewhere else then finding the third and fourth ' and so on. Would that work?

Comment: You could pass a delimiter string `"'"` (a single quote `'` in double quotes `"`) to `strtok()` to prevent it breaking at a space in the data content (such as in a song name or in a description), but you would get the space(s) between the `'` delimiters as tokens, which you would have to ignore.

Comment: [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469681/c-get-all-substrings-between-two-delimiters#comment115748103_65469681) is feasible, using `strchr()` from the position of the previously found `'` + 1.

Comment: Or you could use `cnt = sscanf(line, " %[^']'%[^']' '%[^']' '%[^']'", cmd, arg1, arg2, arg3)` to parse the command and `'`-delimited arguments.

Comment: Sounds great, I'll give it a try, thanks a lot for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"would formatting input in a different manner make it any easier?"*.

Eg, given the  following multi  delimiter string  :

```
char str[] = {"this,is|a:multi.delimited$string"};  
char *dup = strdup(str);
if(dup)
char *tok = strtok(dup,",");
if(tok)
{
     printf("%s\n", tok);
     tok = strtok(NULL, "|");
     if(tok)
     {
          printf("%s\n", tok);
           tok = strtok(NULL, ":");
           if(tok)
           {
                 //and so on through each unique delimiter
```

Illustrates how  string parsing with different delimiters can be simply done using  strtok().